# Make S3 listen to public Ip and port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ip, port

I am trying to send data from a socket test tool to S3. I have synced S3 with EC2. Do I still need to make S3 listen to the Public IP and Port? If Yes, is there any commands or steps to make it listen to a port?

Comment: you have to make bucket public , but that is not suggested best practice what you can do is make bucket listen from specific ip

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following in the policy, select the bucket -> properties -> permissions -> Add Bucket Policy and You can modify the policy

```
{
  "Version": "****-**-**",
  "Id": "s3AllowPolicy",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32",
            "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where exactly this piece will go, I tried and failed with error invalid json format. this is the existing bucket policy

Comment: You need to put it under your bucket policy. select the bucket -> properties -> permissions -> Add Bucket Policy

Comment: I don't see "add bucket policy," I can see only the bucket policy which is existing already

Comment: Yes, My answer is different from default policy. Can you share the policy you see.

Comment: I generated a policy as well, couldn't find a way to add it

Comment: Ihave attached the SS of that, check in answer section

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: you have not made changes as per my answer. Can you only keep my change in the policy and comment your changes and check ?

Comment: what will be the resource, how it can be found? in the existing one GetBucketAcl it was "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nithya-trainingbucket" and for putobject it was "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nithya-trainingbucket/AWSLogs/******/Config/*"

Comment: `Resource` is the ARN for your bucket here. You can mention `*` for now.

Comment: I am getting this error 
Error
Policy has invalid resource

Comment: if I add arn:aws:s3:::nithya-trainingbucket" this resource then I am getting this error Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

Comment: saved successfully, but I am not receiving the data

Comment: _What do you mean not receiving data_ Are the files not being uploaded to s3 ?

Comment: thanks for your help. here in my case I am trying to send a raw hex data, I guess S3 doesn't allow it. do you have any idea how raw hex data can be sent to cloud and used for further analysis. If yes which service does that?

Comment: Like you want to store a file with raw hex data ?

Comment: Yes, the data which I receive in my socket test tool is in hex, I want to take it into aws and keep storing

Comment: Well, it is still a file, you should be able to upload it, rather don't upload hex data, aws provide [redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_HEX.html) which you can use to convert `data` to `hex`

Comment: Do we need any code to upload the data as a file/object?

Comment: My scenario here is, I am using socket tool to send and receive data in the same tool. there is a option where we can use our cloud's public ip and push the data into the cloud. the tool is now linked to my Ip, but I am facing trouble transferring the data. I have sent the data from the socket tool. I couldn't figure out how to receive the data as file.

Comment: As per your previous suggestion the S3 bucket permission is set to listen to the Ip and port. but will that receive the data directly?

Comment: S3, does not scan for your contents to understand what kind of data is being uploaded, so if you want to upload a file which contains `hex` code, you can do it just as you upload any other files and you don't need any additional changes for the policy.